# Magento - hide Not Visible Individually Configurable Products in Admin Manage Products List

Tags: magento-1.6

When you are in admin in Magento and you go to Catalog > Manage Products there is the list of products on the store. A product that has say 6 options using attribute will display 7 of the same product in the Manage Products listing (1 will have visibility of Catalog, Search) and the other 6 will have visibility of "Not Visible Individually" and these are each the options for the main product).

My question is how can we like hide the products with the 6 options from the Manage Products list so the list doesnt look so crowded. Is there a module somewhere which hides them all in the main product and when you click the main product, then you can see the other 6 products? Just to tidy up the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute filters, dropdowns on the top of the Manage product grid. On top of the Visibility column you can get to choose from four different criterias (as shown in the picture beneath). In your case, choose "Not Visible Individually".

Then hit "Search" button on the upper right corner (as shown in the picture) to filter the list.

[image: Manage product filters]